# how to best achieve string to number mapping in a c program

Tags: c, performance

I have a definite set of strings and its corresponding numbers:

```
kill -> 1
live -> 2
half_kill -> 3
dont_live -> 4
```

List is of 30 such strings and their number mapping.

If user enters "kill", I need to return 1 and if he enters "dont_live" I need to return 4.

How should I achieve this in c program? I am looking for an efficient solution because this operation needs to be done 100s of times.

- should I put them in #define in my .h file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct entry {
    char *str;
    int n;
};

struct entry dict[] = {
    "kill", 1,
    "live", 2,
    "half_kill", 3,
    "dont_live", 4,
    0,0
};

int
number_for_key(char *key)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *name = dict[i].str;
    while (name) {
        if (strcmp(name, key) == 0)
            return dict[i].n;
        name = dict[++i].str;
    }
    return 0;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("enter your keyword: ");
    char s[100]; scanf("%s", s);
    printf("the number is: %d\n", number_for_key(s));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a quick and dirty program, to illustrate the use of structs and a "find" function. Take more care while initializing things and avoid that _scanf_ for strings.

Comment: Thanks. This looks good. I have one question though. If I use `enum` instead, would that be cheaper thatn strcmp? I believe `enum` would also need to do something similar to find what we want?

Comment: @hari: I can't imagine how to use an _enum_ here – if the input is coming from the user. When you say `enum { ZERO, ONE }`, both are just *ints*. So, you can't compare them by name to find the correct one. Thus, you need strings involved and structs are the way to go (I think).

Comment: @hari: Right. The answer from @sigjuice shows a really faster way to implement this -- I'd go with it if the amount of data is considerable.

Comment: I will use your solution and will profile the code. If need be I will g for @sigjuice 's code.

Answer (score 9):

Sort your table, and use the standard library function [bsearch](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch) to perform a binary search.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct entry {
    char *str;
    int n;
};

/* sorted according to str */
struct entry dict[] = {
    "dont_live", 4,
    "half_kill", 3,
    "kill", 1,
    "live", 2,
};

int compare(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
     const struct entry *e1 = s1;
     const struct entry *e2 = s2;

     return strcmp(e1->str, e2->str);
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct entry *result, key = {argv[1]};

    result = bsearch(&key, dict, sizeof(dict)/sizeof(dict[0]),
                     sizeof dict[0], compare);
    if (result)
        printf("%d\n", result->n);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's what you get when you run the program.

```
$ ./a.out kill
1
$ ./a.out half_kill
3
$ ./a.out foo
<no output>
```

PS: I reused portions of sidyll's program. My answer should now be CC BY-SA compliant :p

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach:

```
int get_index(char *s)
{
    static const char mapping[] = "\1.kill\2.live\3.half_kill\4.dont_live";
    char buf[sizeof mapping];
    const char *p;
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, ".%s", s);
    p = strstr(mapping, buf);
    return p ? p[-1] : 0;
}
```

The `.` mess is to work around `kill` being a substring of `half_kill`. Without that issue you could simply search for the string directly.

Comment: This is a cool solution but strstr would again go and call strncmp. So, I better call strncmp directly.

Comment: A good `strstr` algorithm may more quickly rule out positions that can't match. `strncmp` inherently needs to compare left-to-right due to the requirement to return the sign of the lexicographic difference.

Comment: Thanks for that info. BTW, what do you mean by "good strstr"?

Comment: Well there are many different ways `strstr` could be implemented. See http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/index.html

Answer (score 3):

If it is a very short list of strings then a simple block of `if`s will be more than sufficient

```
if (0 == strcmp(value, "kill")) {
  return 1;
}
if (0 == strcmp(value, "live")) {
  return 2;
}
...
```

If the number approach 10 I would begin to profile my application though and consider a map style structure.

Comment: I have some 30 such mappings to take care of and they are not going to increase in numbers (for now - at least). BTW, will this be the most efficient way? How about enums?

Comment: @hari, if i had 30 or so i would start to consider a mapping / hashing structure of sorts. Using an `enum` is also acceptable but you'll need to implement a method to convert from a name to an `enum` value which will have the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a fixed set of strimgs, you have two options: generate a ***perfect hashing*** function (check gperf or cmph) or create a ***trie*** so that you never have to check charcters more than once.
Compilers usually use perfect hashes to recognize a language keyword, in your case I would probably go with the trie, it should be the fastest way (but nothing beats direct measurement!)

Answer (score 0):

Is it really a bottleneck? You should worry about efficiency only if the simple solution proves to be too slow.

Having said that, possible speed improvements are checking the lengths first:

```
If it's 4 characters then it could be "kill" or "live"
If it's 9 characters then it could be "half_kill" or "dont_live"
```

or checking the first character in a switch statement:

```
switch (string[0]) {
case 'k':
    if (strcmp(string, "kill") == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
case 'l':
    ...
default:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not the bottleneck but because this application is doing a lot of string processing and this particular piece of code is going to get called a lot of times, I just want to make sure that whatever I design, should be best possible/feasible. On another note, do you see any problem in using `enum`? I believe they provide neater solution.

Comment: enum is a good idea, just don't use 'magic' values on your code. It's clearer to write `KILL` and `LIVE` than `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Use hashmap/ hashtable i think this would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an Enumunerator?

```
int main(void) {

  enum outcome { kill=1, live, half_kill, dont_live };

  printf("%i\n", kill);       //1
  printf("%i\n", dont_live);  //4
  printf("%i\n", half_kill);  //3
  printf("%i\n", live);       //2

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Create a list of const values:

const int kill = 1;
const int live = 2;
const int half_kill = 3;

etc

Comment: Useless advice, this has nothing to do with OP's question that's about mapping strings.